# ADF BC composite ViewObject based on 3 entities - insert

Tags: oracle-adf

Is it possible to insert a ViewObject that is based on 3 entities? Or just view and update?

I created ViewObject that is based on 3 entities. All entities have foreign keys and associations between them. Selecting and updating this composite entity works fine. But insert doesn't. ADF version 11.1.2.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created your VO, did you mark the second and third EOs you added as updateable?
Note that if the realtionship is 1 to many you might need to code what to do in an insert situation.
More on this here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/web.111230/e16182/bcadvvo.htm#CEGCAJCI
42.9 Creating a View Object with Multiple Updatable Entities